# Can not change screen resolution past recommended in Windows 11

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution

Windows 11 gives me options to change my resolution

[image]

When I attempt to choose something higher than recommended, it reverts back to the recommended and screws up with my monitor layout! Before I try to change the layout, my layout is

[image]

After I change the layout (and it reverts automatically) it converts this to

[image]

My GeForce GTX 1070 Ti graphic card is up to date

Answer (score 1):

Do you have DSR enabled in NVIDIA Control Panel? It is likely that your monitor doesn't support a resolution higher than what the monitor is capable of (1920x1080) and therefore reverts back to normal when you try. DSR makes it so you can select higher resolutions but not every monitor will support this.